# Object doesn't support this property or method when using AutoFilter

Tags: excel, vba

We want to use some AutoFilter method in some report and are retrieving Run-Time error "438" Object doesn't support this property or method. Please have a look at the code snipped, where this error occurs.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("someworksheet").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:= _
    Range("somerange"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
```

When I had a look at the object explorer, I found out, that the AutoFilter - method is a member of the Worksheet class, but not a member of the Worksheets - class. So how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using? The Add2 method only applies to the latest version.

Comment: VBA: Retail 7.1.1075

Comment: Version 1806 (Build 10228.20080)

Comment: @RWatermelon have you tried [`SortFields.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sortfields.add) instead of [`SortFields.Add2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sortfields.add2)?